# Error curl/curl.h: No such file or directory

Tags: windows, curl, dev-c++, curlpp

I am using Dev-C++ and downloaded curlpp from
[here](https://codeload.github.com/jpbarrette/curlpp/zip/refs/tags/v0.8.1)
When I try to compile the included example (file example00.cpp, directory examples) Dev-C++ throw me the error I have written in the title.

I looked for this file in my system, but it seems it doesn´t even exists :P

Answer (score 0):

curlpp depends on libcurl, so you must have libcurl and its dependencies available on your system.